# vim-snipmate change end cursor location

Tags: vim, snipmate

I have just started using `vim-snipmate` so i might be doing it the wrong way. I defined a custom snippet like

```
snippet model
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  module.exports = mongoose.model('${1}',mongoose.Schema({
    ${2}
  }));
```

The problem is that till `${1}` it all works fine but in `${2}` i want to use some other of my snippets but the moment i use `TAB` it assumes the end of `$2` and jumps to the end. How can i change that behaviour if it is possible. Or am i going some wrong way of defining snippets in here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `${2}` to `${0}` if you want to to use a snippet at that position.